# org-capture-templates allows file+headline to capture to a headline. How can I capture to a sub-headline?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have an org file tracking my tasks across various projects:

*work.org*

```
* Job 1
** Tasks
*** TODO rewrite frontend in coldfusion
* Job 2
** Tasks
*** TODO Convince boss to buy stadium
```

I can do an org-capture-template to capture tasks to `work.org`'s `Job 1` header or `Job 2` header, but what about `Job 1 > Tasks`, and same for `Job 2`?

For example:

```
  (setq org-capture-templates
          ("j" "Job 1" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "/work.org") "Job 1")
           "* TODO %? \n"))
```

I tried, in place of "Job 1," "Job 1 Tasks," but that created a new top-level headline called "Job 1 Tasks." Based on a [somewhat unrelated stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036132/how-to-link-to-second-level-heading-in-external-org-file) answer, I tried "*Job 1 Tasks", but again, that just created a new top-level headline.

**How can I refer to a sub-header in an org-capture-template?**

Comment: I haven't checked but I don't think you can do that: it will search for a headline, so the matcher must say e.g. "Tasks", but it's not possible to disambiguate the first `Tasks` from the second. But I may be wrong.

Comment: I was wrong: `file+olp`, as @TianshuWang points out in his answer, does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `file+olp` like:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      ("j" "Job 1" entry (file+olp ,(concat org-directory "/work.org") "Job 1" "Works")
       "* TODO %? \n"))
```

For more details, please refer to the doc of `org-capture-templates` through `C-h v org-capture-templates`.

Comment: I forgot about `file+olp` ...

Comment: I thought it might be necessary to use `file+function` and write you own function to prompt and find the right location.